# git "compressing objects" crash - Ubuntu

Tags: git, shell, ubuntu, cron

I've got a bit of an odd one, and it's causing me some issues.
I have a cron job that runs git and essentially "backs up" a bunch of development websites.

I also put this cron job on two other servers we run because those two have specific websites that were edited directly and thus don't have their own backups.

Both the development server and the first live server run this job (a custom sh file) just fine, but the last one crashes the entire server and brings down about 10 different websites for a few seconds. Since this is running every day, that's really not a good thing.

Here's the .sh file that's run:

```
/root/git.sh

#!/bin/sh
git=$(which git)

dt=$(date +"%d-%m-%y")

eval `/usr/bin/ssh-agent -s`
/usr/bin/ssh-add /root/git

shopt -s nullglob
shopt -s dotglob

cd /home/
for d1 in */ ; do
        cd /home/$d1
        for d2 in */ ; do
                cd /home/$d1/$d2
                if [ ! -d ".git" ]; then
                        echo Skipping $d2
                        continue
                fi

                echo Adding repo at $d2

                git add -A
                git commit -a -m $dt
                git push --all origin
                cd ..
        done
done
cd ~

shopt -u nullglob
```

(/root/git is obviously a private key file, which works of course)

and the cron command running it:

```
/etc/cron.d/git

# Git Backup
MAILTO=""
0 19 * * * root /usr/local/bin/setlock -n /tmp/cronlock.3788462754.179891 sh -c $'/root/git.sh &> /dev/null'
```

and finally the crash:
[image: Crash]

So, aside from myself being terrible at bourne shell, I have no idea what's going on. If I knew where log files for this would be, maybe, but I don't.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was git's packing was using a ton of memory and the provider automatically restarted the VPS when that became a problem (compressing bit files)

the solution: edited the .sh file to include git config directives (in case someone edited the config later down the road)

```
#!/bin/sh

git=$(which git)
dt=$(date +"%d-%m-%Y")

git config --global pack.windowMemory "100m"
git config --global pack.packSizeLimit "100m"
git config --global pack.threads "1"

eval `/usr/bin/ssh-agent -s`
/usr/bin/ssh-add /root/git

shopt -s nullglob
shopt -s dotglob

cd /home/
for d1 in */ ; do
        cd /home/$d1
        for d2 in */ ; do
                cd /home/$d1/$d2
                if [ ! -d ".git" ]; then
                        echo Skipping $d2
                        continue
                fi

                echo Adding repo at $d2

                git add -A
                git commit -a -m $dt
                git push --all origin
                cd ..
        done
done
cd ~

shopt -u nullglob
```